# How to print the value in same page using php template

Tags: php

I want to display the value entered in the form field in the same page. I have created custom php template for the page. Its showing 404 when I submit. Please help how to achieve this.

```
<table> 
<form action="" method="POST"> 
<tr> 
<td> Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="name"></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td><input value="Submit" type="submit" /></td></tr> 
</form> 
</table> 

<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') 
{
 $NAME = $_POST["name"]; 
echo $NAME;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

you should set the form action to `custom_template.php` with this change, when the form is submitted, it will post the data back to the same page custom_template.php, and your PHP script will process the form data and display the entered name on the same page.

```
<table> 
<form action="custom_template.php" method="POST"> <!-- Ensure form action is set to the same page -->
<tr> 
<td> Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="name"></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td><input value="Submit" type="submit" /></td></tr> 
</form> 
</table> 

<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $name = $_POST["name"]; 
    echo "<p>Name: $name</p>"; // Displaying the entered name
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. I found the answer. I am using this template in WordPress. I changed the input field name to some other name and its working correctly. I kept form action as blank

Comment: Are you aware that template files are *never* called directly in WordPress?